# capturing jquery click event bubbling

Tags: jquery

The web page I'm working on is a list of `candidate-tile`s which look like this (this is actually a `mustache` template:

```
<div class="candidate-tile">
    <div class="candidate-image">
        <img src="<%= candidate.image %>" width="50px" height=auto />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <h3 class="candidate-name"><%= candidate.name %></h3>
        <h6 class="candidate-dept"><%= candidate.dept %></h6>
        <span class="label label-info"><%= candidate.hostel %></span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <span class="check">&#10003;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to toggle a class when the checkbox is clicked. Something like this:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("candidate_selected");
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. How can I capture on the `checkbox` and make sure that the click event can be handled?

### UPDATE

I just tested that there is some problem with click events in the `mustache` template. I'm using `sammy.js` to load the template. On the rest of the page (which is fixed and not being rendered using mustache / sammy) click events are working fine. But for some reason click events are not working on the part rendered by mustache / sammy. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Is there something I can do to explain the situation better? Is sammy listening for events and not letting jquery handle it?

### ANOTHER UPDATE

As far as I can understand the problem is that the `candidate-tile`s are not loaded when the  js file containing the `click` handler is loaded. Items are loaded later but by that time, I am guessing, all event registration has already happened and hence there are no events bound to  new DOM elements generated. Am I right in thinking so? If yes, what is the way out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe this http://api.jquery.com/change/ ?

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I don't think, It will not work, check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M98fE/. It is working.

Comment: Response to ANOTHER UPDATE: The container move in my answer will allow the handler to attach to elements of class 'checkbox' even if they are created after the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine. It will toggle the class `candidate_selected` on the `div` with class `candidate-tile`. Try putting a `console.log` into the closure to see that the click is firing.

If you are creating the tiles dynamically with AJAX, you may need to use this:

`$('#container').on('click', '.checkbox', function(){....`

`container` would be a `div` level above the `candidate-tile divs`.